# Keep HangFire application awake on IIS in .NET Core environment

Tags: hangfire

I am having difficulties with: IApplicationLifetime CancellationTokens:
ApplicationStarted,
ApplicationStopped
in my .NET core application using HangFire batch application.

The delegates passed to ApplicationStarted.Register() and ApplicationStopped.Register() do not get called.  I am using .NET Core version 1.0.

Using below workaround in .NET Core (use appropriate Configuration for your app, inject your own "logger") inside the Startup.Configure(..) method.  Note RestartURL:URL is a URL to your application - a lightweight hit.

Current workaround to keep batch process alive:

```
var batchProcessKeepAliveTimer = new Timer();
        batchProcessKeepAliveTimer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Configuration["Data:RestartURL:URL"]);
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            logger.Log("Polling batch restart 60 milli second intervals");
        };
        batchProcessKeepAliveTimer.Enabled = true;
        double result = 60000;//default value in milliseconds
        if (Double.TryParse(Configuration["Data:RestartURL:PollingInterval"], out result))
            batchProcessKeepAliveTimer.Interval = result;
```

Draw backs is:  When app pool is manually shut down and restarted, no guarantee that Startup will be called right away.  I find that I need to make an explicit HTTP request so that the application pool can re-instantiate the Startup objects.  In other words, I need to make a single HTTP call to bootstrap this timer.

However, if the Startup has been instantiated like this, timer can go on for a long time, until it is shut down.  Would be less maintenance for your application if the Timer interval is less than IdleTime.

Anybody have a better working approach - especially using .NET core cancellation tokens as above?

Comment: I don't think .net Core + IIS play nicely for "always on" applications currently. You could run .net Core + Kestrel as a windows service on the server and use IIS as a reverse proxy to forward the traffic to the specific port the windows service is listening to. For internal projects I have quite a few ASP Core sites with hangfire running as windows services (using topshelf) without issue.

Comment: Is this still the case? Can we do Recurring Jobs in .net Core 2.1 yet?